# Talking Tom Hardware

Tags: audio, microphone

We want to make Talking Tom doll.
Talking Tom is an IPhone App. When you speak to it, it echoes your voice with voice of child.
Is there any ready scheme to construct it.
I mean scheme from mic to audio output, that will change frequency of voice in output.
And how we can do it?

Comment: Maybe you can explain in the post what a Talking Tom doll is, and what behavior of it you would like to replicate.

Comment: Stick an iphone in a stuffed toy?

Comment: What do you mean with your last question "And how we can do it?"?

Comment: What are the ways to do it

Comment: If there were a "*ready scheme*" (**schematic** is a preferred term), there would be a "ready product", and where would that leave you?

Comment: Do you have an engineering question, or do you just want someone to give you a schematic? It sounds like the latter. Have you tried [google](http://google.com/search?q=talking+tom+doll+schematic)? Nothing there? Then I guess the answer is "no".

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the [RTS0072](http://masterkit.ru/zip/RTS0072.pdf) chip. It's a voice changer IC, which can do robotic and amplified voice, but also higher and lower voice. A kid's voice is higher, most of the time.

There's an example circuit [here](http://www.electroniccircuitsdesign.com/audio-circuits/voice-changer-circuit-diagram-using-rts0072b.html):

[image]

> This circuit design project is very simple and require few external electronic parts . Circuit must be powered from a DC power supply circuit that will provide a fixed output voltage between 3 and 5 volts. This circuit has various voice effects like transposing voice (higher or lower), amplifying voice and robot voice. As you can see in this project is used a 9 volts DC power supply , because this circuit uses a LM386 audio amplifier IC that will amplify the output signal.

In addition to that, I'd like to say you can select the voice effect with the DIPswitch.